# How i can convert "• Robbery No. 1 occurred on Johnny's person on Tuesday in the park" to prolog rule/fact?

Tags: prolog

How i can convert "• Robbery No. 1 occurred on Johnny's person on Tuesday in the park" to prolog rule/fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
robbery(1, johnny, tuesday, park).
```

... as 1 of many ways, depending on how you want to use the info.